# Thread sleep until notified from another class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Im currently making an infoscreen to display text and pictures on. I have a problem regarding the text part of it.

I have a JFrame as the mainwindow of the displayer. To this frame i add jpanels to display the text and the pictures. then when it's been displayed, i remove the panel again. This part is easy with the pictures because i know how long i want the displayed. for the text however, i need to put the thread to sleep and then wake it back up when my scrollPane has reach the bottom.

Here is where i add the panels

```
for (File f : files) {
            String fileName = f.getName();
            if (fileName.endsWith(".txt")) {
                TextPanel txtpan = new TextPanel(f, this, current.getFormat().getFont());
                add(txtpan);
                pack();
                //Input sleep here
                remove(txtpan);

            }
            if (fileName.endsWith(".png") || fileName.endsWith(".jpg") || fileName.endsWith("bmp")) {
                AlbumPanel albumpan = new AlbumPanel(connect, f, this, current.getFormat().getPicColor(), current.getFormat().getPicLength());
                add(albumpan);
                pack();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(current.getFormat().getPicLength() * 1000 + 520);

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
                remove(albumpan);
            }
```

and this is the textpanel i add

```
public class TextPanel extends JPanel {

File file;
JFrame presWin;
ArrayList<String> lines;
Font font;
JTextArea textArea;

public TextPanel(File file, JFrame presWin, Font font) {
    this.file = file;
    this.presWin = presWin;
    this.font = font;
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    readFile();
    if (!lines.isEmpty()) {
        displayWords();
    }

}

private void readFile() {
    lines = new ArrayList();
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}


private void displayWords() {
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setFont(font);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50));
    for (String s : lines) {
        textArea.append(s + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }


    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollpane.setPreferredSize(this.getPreferredSize());
    scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollpane.setViewportView(textArea);
    System.out.println(scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
    Timer t=new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue()+1);
            if (scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue()>=scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum()) {
                ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
            }
        }
    });
    t.setRepeats(true);
    t.start();



    add(scrollpane);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(presWin.getWidth(), presWin.getHeight());
}
```

ive tried having a while loop waiting for a boolean in the textpanel

Comment: You shouldn't use `sleep` inside EDT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) and [notify()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify())

[Example](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/)

Comment: I can not get this to work. I havent really done much with multithreading :/

Comment: Never mind, googled another wait /notify question here and found the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Don't sleep the thread at all. Instead do all the work you needed initially and then let the thread exit.

When you want to do the processing at the end just create a new thread for that. (If you really are doing enough to warrant a new thread).